# I have a javascript that must generate in runtime. In MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a javascript that must generate in runtime. that is in controller i get it as a string to my view .Like asp literal control is there any method in mvc 3 razor.??? Help me Masters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   @Html.Raw(Model.YourJavaScriptString)
</script>
```

Comment: Its not working boss...

Comment: What is not working? You need to give us more information.

Comment: i am trying to plot over google map with coordinates.that is not executing .it doesnt showing any error.But it is not making any change in my map.

Comment: Thanks Erik it work but need not to put in between the script tag         @Html.Raw(Model.YourJavaScriptString) only needed... Thanks u very much master...!

Comment: No problem. Please mark my post as "Answer" :)